# Format Java/JavaScript using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm looking for a solution to format some code that's input through a form.

Take the following code for example

```
function whatever(){
var test=1;
var    test2=2;}
```

Dose anyone know of a library that'll take this and turn it into

```
function whatever() {
  var test = 1;
  var test2 = 2;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=format+javascript+code

Comment: https://github.com/einars/js-beautify might do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a library like [js-beautify](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify), if you need to access it in node or otherwise programmatically.